# Calculating difference in angle between two angles

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with directions in degrees (0-360) and I would like to get the vectorized difference in degrees (0-180) to a main direction.

`main_direction: 340`

| Item | Degrees |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 10 |
| 1 | 40 |
| 2 | 0 |
| 3 | 320 |
| 4 | 80 |

Now I would like to get the absolute difference betwen the main direction (340) and the direction, for each value in the dataframe, so my result would look like this:

| Item | Difference |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 30 |
| 1 | 60 |
| 2 | 20 |
| 3 | 20 |
| 4 | 100 |

It should be able to solve it with something like:

```
df['Difference'] = df['Degrees']-main_direction) %360
```

or

```
df['Difference'] = np.where(main_direction-df['Degrees'] < 0, df['Degrees']-main_direction + 360, abs(df['Degrees']-main_direction))
```

But neither of these are giving me the correct result.

Comment: Please include a machine-readable form of the dataframe in question and a complete python file that loads it, so that you are providing a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that others can run to reproduce your problem.

Comment: What is the dtype of Degrees? If it is not integer, add .astype(int)

Comment: @JoeFerndz Why would you store degrees as ints? There is nothing about degrees which make them naturally whole numbers.

Comment: Agree. I am assuming that the value maybe a string. @Danny, can you please share the dtypes for these columns please.

Comment: @JoeFerndz The data is set as dtype: float64. I doubt that is causing the issue though

Comment: You didn't tag this pandas anywhere ot state that you're looking for a vectorized calculation between a pandas dataframe, and your scalar `main_direction`. (Not just base Python)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```py
def diff(angle):
  res = (angle-main_direction)%360
  if res < 180:
    return res
  else:
    return (360-res)
```

OR you can use lambda function

```py
diff = lambda x: (x-main_direction)%360 if (x-main_direction)%360<180 else 360-(x-main_direction)%360
```

```py
# Example
main_direction = 320
angles = [10,40,0,320,80]
for angle in angles:
  print(diff(angle))
```

Comment: For the case of 10 degrees and 340 for main_direction that gives 330

Comment: This works really well. I think what I did wrong was introduce a abs() while the modulu % already handles that. I adjusted it a little to perform on columns better:  res = (angle-main_direction)%360   &   np.minimum(360-df['res'], df['res'])